# For certain URI, is it possible to log the rule violation instead of returning access deny?

Tags: mod-security

We have set up Modsecurity CRS with Nginx and we are in the phase of customization (or writing the exclusion rules).

We'd like to know if it is possible that modsec can only log the exception for certain URIs without adding up the score while the rest of the URIs still being protected. Or, whenever it tries to return Access Deny, it will check if it for certain URIs first. I've read a couple of tutorials and they suggest either setting detection mode or the threshold to a huge number, while we'd like to start the protection now but don't want to affect certain URIs as they are critical for business. If modsec finds rules violation for those URIs, we'd like modsec to log it only and we'll write exclusion rules after reviewing the logs.

Modsec verion: v3.0.3

Nginx version: 1.13.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is certainly possible, as you could have different settings per [`location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).**

According to [Installing OWASP CRS](https://www.modsecurity.org/CRS/Documentation/install.html#nginx-with-modsecurity-2-x-compiled):

> Once ModSecurity is compiled in you will have to specify both
>   `ModSecurityEnabled` and `ModSecurityConfig` within any `location` block
>   where you want ModSecurity enabled. An example would look similar to
>   below.
>
> ```
> location / {
>     ModSecurityEnabled on;
>     ModSecurityConfig modsec_includes.conf;
> }
> ```

However, Nginx's blog article [Compiling and Installing ModSecurity for NGINX Open Source](https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-and-installing-modsecurity-for-open-source-nginx/) has a bit different form for these directives, and the ability to use them directly within the `server {}` block:

> ```
> server {
>     modsecurity on;
>     modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;
> }
> ```

You must choose those that apply to your installation, but you'll get the idea. This example is based on the latter syntax, but if you can't apply the rules directly like this, you could simply use different `ModSecurityConfig` files for different locations.

The detection only mode is configured with `SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly`.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    modsecurity on;
    modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;

    location / {
       modsecurity_rules '
           SecRuleEngine On
       ';
    }

    location /business-critical {
       modsecurity_rules '
           SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly
       ';
    }
}
```

**This is best to be a temporary solution for two reasons:**

1. Your business critical URIs may also have vulnerabilities.
2. There will be a lot of noise in your logs from the constant automated attacks.

I'd suggest testing through every feature and acceptable use case. Then, find false positive detections by limiting the search to your own IP address. Once you know the rules that will cause problems to your application, you could disable them with `SecRuleRemoveById` and enable rest of the protection, e.g.

```
    location /business-critical {
       modsecurity_rules '
           SecRuleEngine On
           SecRuleRemoveById 941100 941120 941160 941180 949110 980130
       ';
    }
```

Comment: Hi Esa, thanks so much for your detailed answer! I'll be testing it out and  there is one point I didn't quite follow. What did you mean by "find false positive detections by limiting the search to your own IP address"?

Comment: If you don't limit it, you might confuse some actual attacks to these false positives you are trying to find by performing normal operations.

Comment: Hi Esa, hope you don't mind I continue to ask in the same thread but should I open a new questions, then please feel free to let me know. Is it possible to set DetectionOnly per location per rule? The closest I can get is `ctl:ruleEngine On|Off|DetectionOnly` but unlike `ctl:ruleRemoveById` I cannot specify Rule Id there. Thanks.